# Kafka S3 sink connector failing with 22 topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

I am trying to use Kafka S3 sink connector to push the data from 22 topics to S3 bucket.
While doing this, I am getting an error saying

`

```
ERROR [prod-partnerbilling-sink-v3|task-2] WorkerSinkTask{id=prod-partnerbilling-sink-v3-2} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:193)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:609)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:329)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:232)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:201)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:186)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:241)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

`

But when I use the same connector config for 2 batches of 11 topics each out of the 22 topics, it works fine.

I want to know the root cause of this error.

Comment: The root cause is that you're batching too many records and you've not increased heap space. We don't know how large your records are, what your heap settings are currently at, or what your connector config looks like to really help further.  Can you please [edit] to clarify all those?

Comment: @OneCricketeer the issue was resolved after I lowered my s3.part.size from 50MB to 25MB

Comment: Increasing the heap size would also work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved after I lowered my s3.part.size from 50MB to 25MB.